# How can I get width and height from imageview or bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-drawable

I searched a lot on google, stackoverflow,...

I found and tried all of these :

```
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getBackground()).getBitmap();
int w = b.getWidth();
int h = b.getHeight();
```

---

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = imageView.getDrawingCache();
int w = b.getWidth();
int h = b.getHeight();
```

---

```
imageView.getWidth(); 
imageView.getHeight();
```

---

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage);
int h = d.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
int w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
```

But every methods gives the same result. I can take photo in landscape mode and portrait mode. Everytime **width is 1024** and **height is 768** But I wait **portrait** mode height must be **1024** and **width must be 768**

Please someone help me.

Comment: There's no question here... the methods getWidth and getHeight return the width/height of a bitmap. What's the problem?

Comment: Android can scale the image to fit your View. If you really have a View that is 768w x 1024h and your photo is 1024w x 768h, then you can set the scaleType in your XML, create some Java code to do the same. Or, if you're bold,m you can write your own code to adjust and scale the image to fit your view.

Comment: everytime it gives same result , width 1024 height 748,

Comment: portrait mode and landscape mode it gives same result

Comment: did you specify a horizontal layout for your imageviews or bitmaps? if not it will return the same sizes..because honestly those are their dimensions.. but if you create a horizontal layout and specify the dimensions to change on rotate then you will have diff dimensions.. am i lucid? sir?

Comment: My purpose is detect a photo is taken from camera landscape or portrait

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to getting image size vs the ImageView size?